# Time Travel functions in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, time-travel

Can anyone recommend for/against the time-travel functions in postgresql's contrib/spi module?  Is there an example available anywhere?

Tnx

Comment: I always hear people saying how much better postgresql is than mysql, but now you tell me it has time travel?? amazing!!

Comment: :-)  'Time travel' is the ability to see the DB as it was in the past - i.e., what values were present in a table at some point earlier on.  Have a loot at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/contrib-spi.html.

Comment: Greetings from the past! ‎

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument for time-travel would be being able to look at tables that are updated often at an earlier insertion/deletion point. Say a table of stock prices for a firms investment portfolio.
The argument against would be the extra storage space it eats up.

Here is an [Example](http://www.pgcluster.org/browser/postgresql-8.2.3/contrib/spi/timetravel.example?rev=3) of use.

Comment: I found the file in the Github repo: http://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/spi/timetravel.example

Answer (score 3):

See [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125877/versioning-database-persisted-objects-how-would-you#126029) for an alternative approach to historical reporting.