# Database history for client usage

Tags: vb.net, oracle, database-design

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to have a history on a database, to track any Insert/Delete/Update that is done.  The history data will need to be coded into the front-end since it will be used by the users.  Creating "history tables" (a copy of each table used to store history) is not a good way to do this, since the data is spread across multiple tables.

At this point in time, my best idea is to create a few History tables, which the tables would reflect the output I want to show to the users.  Whenever a change is made to specific tables, I would update this history table with the data as well.

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to go about would be.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I am using Oracle + VB.NET

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323065/323109#323109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used very successfully a model where every table has an audit copy - the same table with a few additional fields (time stamp, user id, operation type), and 3 triggers on the first table for insert/update/delete.
I think this is a very good way of handling this, because tables and triggers can be generated from a model and there is little overhead from a management perspective.
The application can use the tables to show an audit history to the user (read-only).

Comment: @dotjoe: The audit table is a different table, not more records in the same table.

Comment: Correct. The audit tables have no contraints or indices, just raw data. It's purpose is auditing, hence the name. If you really need to pull back data into the UI, that's probably a different business case and you may want to design something else as part of the operational model.

Comment: This is what I have right now, but I am having issues rebuilding the data.  The issue is when joining multiple tables to display the data.  The table joins are very problematic in our case.

Comment: @Jon - Do you have a separate primary key for the audit table? That would come in handy. Otherwise, joining on it would be near impossible.

Answer (score 0):

We've got that requirement in our systems. We added two tables, one header, one detail called AuditRow and AuditField. The AuditRow contains one row per row changed in any other table, and the AuditField contains one row per column changed with old value and new value.

We have a trigger on every table that writes a header row (AuditRow) and the needed detail rows (one per changed colum) on each insert/update/delete. This system does rely on the fact that we have a guid on every table that can uniquely represent the row. Doesn't have to be the "business" or "primary" key, but it's a unique identifier for that row so we can identify it in the audit tables. Works like a champ. Overkill? Perhaps, but we've never had a problem with auditors. :-)

And yes, the Audit tables are by far the largest tables in the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky enough to be on Oracle 11g, you could also use the [Flashback Data Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/oracle-database-11g-top-features/11g-transactionmanagement.html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would stay away from triggers.  They can be a nightmare when it comes to debugging and not necessarily the best if you are looking to scale out.

If you are using an PL/SQL API to do the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETEs you could manage this in a simple shift in design without the need (up front) for history tables.

All you need are 2 extra columns, DATE_FROM and DATE_THRU.  When a record is INSERTed, the DATE_THRU is left NULL.  If that record is UPDATEd or DELETEd, just "end date" the record by making DATE_THRU the current date/time (SYSDATE).  Showing the history is as simple as selecting from the table, the one record where DATE_THRU is NULL will be your current or active record.

Now if you expect a high volume of changes, writing off the old record to a history table would be preferable, but I still wouldn't manage it with triggers, I'd do it with the API.

Hope that helps.