# Can we make middle table to simplify query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the below query, I am creating a new table.

```
select * from TableA, tableB, (another query to make new table)TableC
where condition
```

This makes my query look long and awful. I don't know if there is a way to make a temporary table to query later.

For example based on the above query:

```
tableC = another query to make new table
select * from tableA, tableB, tableC
where condition
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Common Table Expressions sound like what you are after, but these are not supported in all DBMS. Also, I'd recommend giving [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) a read. Although the ANSI 89 join syntax (`FROM tableA, TableB WHERE..`) is not incorrect, and occasionally has it's place, using Explicit joins is usually easier to read and less prone to error.

Comment: as title, i'm using t-sql, so DBMS is microsoft sql server. thanks for your recommendation :)

Comment: If your only concern is that your query looks long and awful, you don't have an actual problem.  Even using CTE as suggested by others merely re-arranges the keystrokes without adding any value.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It is not really related to the question, but having looked at your queries in pastebin I suspect you have some unwanted cross joins, for instance, is there really no relation between `tblStudent` and `tblReport`? In one of your queries you are creating a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of these two tables. It might be an idea to post your table structure along with your desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTEs are one way to do it

```
With TableC as 
( SELECT ....
)
SELECT * from tableA, tableB, tableC
WHERE condition
```

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.` I meet this error. can you tell me why, please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Fk0B4VAD here is my query. please take a look at this. thanks :)

Comment: Add a `;` as it says :)  ... `use FUH_UNIVERSITY;` - that's the syntax you'll need, but it looks like you will need to specify your table joins properly for the whole thing to work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- Using a [view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) which is the simplest case,
- Using an [Indexed View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986366/how-to-create-materialized-views-in-sql-server) which is a little bit harder, and has pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me I would use a temporary table for the purposes of the query.

You could do something like this;

```
SELECT TA.*, TB.*
INTO #TempTable
FROM TableA AS TA INNER JOIN TableB AS TB ON TA.ID = TB.ID
WHERE ......
```

Then you can use this table's detail for whatever purpose;

```
SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
```

Just remember, it's good practice to `DROP` it at the end.

```
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4394)

Comment: can you tell me, when i reuse this table, i receive error : invalid object name #tableC. thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure you have replaced my "#TempTable" with your "#TableC" in all three statements? Also the temporary table will only be available in your current query.

Comment: The temp table is only valid for the life of the session or until you drop it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PggQ5TLj please watch again for me. i meet that error at line 9 and line 13. thanks :)

Comment: See my SQL Fiddle (edit), I'm unsure why it's not working in your example, but I suspect it doesn't like how you join your tables. (See the comment by @GarethD above)