# Equivalent of Materialised Views in SQL Server

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views, indexed-view

We have something called Materialized Views in Oracle, do we have anything like it in SQL Server. After doing some findings on Google, I feel that Indexed Views can be somewhat similar to it. Can anyone highlight me with the difference between Oracle's Materialised Views and SQL Server's Indexed Views?

Comment: Try a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/06/20/migrating-oracle-materialized-view-to-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link... hope it would be helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986366/how-to-create-materialized-views-in-sql-server), Materilaized Views are called indexed views in SQL Server.

hope this latter will help.