# Indexed views: How to insert value into other table with index views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, triggers, indexed-views

**My table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Balance] (
    [Id]             INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,    
    [Balance]        DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Today_Date]     AS              (CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126))),
    [Date_end]       DATE            NOT NULL,
    [Remaining_Days] AS              (datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end])),
    [In_Months]      AS              (datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end]))/(30),
    [Amount_Monthly] AS              CAST((case when ((datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end]))/30) = 0 then NULL else [Balance]/((datediff(day,CONVERT([char](10),getdate(),(126)),[Date_end]))/30) end) as DECIMAL(18,2)),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

**How it looks like:**

[image: My data]

I want it to **automatically insert** the Amount_Monthly into a new table so it would look like this:

[image: My Months table]

E.g. if it says In_Months = 2 it should fill out January and February's Balance_monthly to 7058,82. I want it to calculate it automatically Just like I made it automatically calculate remaining_days depending on the input.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you read this (regarding "indexed views" in SQL server) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986366/how-to-create-materialized-views-in-sql-server but I think you need Enterprise Edition of SQL Server to use that feature. Otherwise you need trigger(s) &/or stored procedure(s) to add rows into another table when you add/alter data in that existing table. It cannot be undertaken as a "computed column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mahesh
So, @Usedbyalready's answer seemed pretty overkill, I tried making it myself with case inside an update and it works perfectly.

```
UPDATE Months
SET Months.Balance_monthly = 
    CASE 
        WHEN Balance.In_Months > 1 THEN Amount_Monthly          
    END
FROM Balance
JOIN Months 
ON Months.Id <= Balance.In_Months;
```

I also made a trigger that automatically inserts the values into my Months table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Balance_monthly]
ON [dbo].[Balance]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Months
    SET Months.Balance_monthly = 
    ((Balance.In_Months + 12 - Months.Id) / 12) * Amount_Monthly          
    FROM Balance
    CROSS JOIN Months;


END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 12 rows each represents a Month number 1 to 12. I have used a simple union all query in a CTE for this but you may already have a table of numbers to use instead. Then join this where the month number is less than or equal to the [in_Month] column. That join will automatically now multiply the rows of your table by the wanted number of months.

```
;with m12 as (
  select 1 as mn
  union all      select 2      union all      select 3      union all      select 4
  union all      select 5      union all      select 6      union all      select 7
  union all      select 8      union all      select 9      union all      select 10
  union all      select 11     union all      select 12
 )
select
        row_number() over(order by b.id, m12.mn) as [ID]
      , datename(month,dateadd(month,m12.mn - 1,0)) as [Month]
      , b.Amount_Monthly as Balance_Monthly
from Balance b
inner join m12 on m12.mn <= b.in_months
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4fc6f/3

Note you will probably want to include db.balance.id as [balanceid] or similar in the new table so you can trace back to the source row id.

If CTEs are a problem just use a "derived table" instead, e.g.

```
select
        row_number() over(order by b.id, m12.mn) as [ID]
      , datename(month,dateadd(month,m12.mn - 1,0)) as [Month]
      , b.Amount_Monthly as Balance_Monthly
from Balance b
inner join (
              select 1 as mn
              union all      select 2      union all      select 3      union all      select 4
              union all      select 5      union all      select 6      union all      select 7
              union all      select 8      union all      select 9      union all      select 10
              union all      select 11     union all      select 12
           ) as m12 on m12.mn <= b.in_months
```

Comment: I want it inserted into my Months table.

Comment: Did you visit the sqlfiddle? if it isn't correct please alter the question so I can offer something else. But as the question stands what I have offered does exactly what you described as the need.

Comment: just add "into my_months_table" or similar. You still need "the query" to produce the wanted rows.

Comment: I don't really want to paste this every time I get a new value, look how I calculate remaining_days for instance, I want it automatic if possible.

Comment: To achieve the automation you are seeking you need a trigger to get a new row (or changed row) in the existing table to produce between 1 and 12 rows in a different table. But the logic outlined in that query remains valid. I'm not offering to write your triggers for you.

Comment: just so it's clear, you cannot use a "computed column" to manage rows in a different table you needs triggers or perhaps a (job running stored proc). Maybe a "materialized view" would do it for you if you have enterprise edition. nb: The query does not depend on using any CTEs (a derived table would work just as well).

Comment: no, I won't attempt to re-write your question. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Today's Date    New End date    Remaining days  Daily   2015-11 2015-12 2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 2016-04 2016-05 2016-06 2016-07 2016-08 2016-09 2016-10 2016-11 2016-12
                11/30/2015  12/31/2015  1/31/2016   2/28/2016   3/31/2016   4/30/2016   5/31/2016   6/30/2016   7/31/2016   8/31/2016   9/30/2016   10/31/2016  11/30/2016  12/31/2016
10/29/2015  1/4/2016    67   $210.71     $6,321.33   $6,532.04   $842.84     $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-
10/29/2015  1/8/2016    71   $283.24     $8,497.16   $8,780.40   $2,265.91   $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-      $-

it should be like this

Comment: copy and paste in excel

Answer (score 0):

Here amount is not splitting correctly, for example if remaining days in Balance if today date is 2015-12-16 and enddate is 2016-01-31 then remaining days could be 46 days, Here Amount need to split into December Month i.e current Month and January Month, can anyone let me know how to achieve it