# materialized views to indexed views

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a materialized view in Oracle and need to convert that to SQL server. I am not sure how to write the same with indexed view concept.
Here is my materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS_mv 
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
SELECT *
FROM STUD_FUZZY_CERTIFICATIONS; -- some base table
```

Answer (score 2):

AS Marc_s stated **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986540/2118383)**

They're called **indexed views** in SQL Server - read these white papers for more background:

- [Creating an Indexed View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)
- [Improving Performance with SQL Server 2008 Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Basically, all you need to do is:

- create a regular view
- create a clustered index on that view

and you're done!

The tricky part is: the view has to satisfy quite a number of constraints and limitations - those are outlined in the white paper. If you do this - that's all there is. The view is being updated automatically, no maintenance needed.

**Sample**

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
--Set the options to support indexed views.
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,
    QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
--Create view with schemabinding.
IF OBJECT_ID ('Sales.vOrders', 'view') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW Sales.vOrders ;
GO
CREATE VIEW Sales.vOrders
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT SUM(UnitPrice*OrderQty*(1.00-UnitPriceDiscount)) AS Revenue,
        OrderDate, ProductID, COUNT_BIG(*) AS COUNT
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS od, Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS o
    WHERE od.SalesOrderID = o.SalesOrderID
    GROUP BY OrderDate, ProductID;
GO
--Create an index on the view.
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1 
    ON Sales.vOrders (OrderDate, ProductID);
GO
--This query can use the indexed view even though the view is 
--not specified in the FROM clause.
SELECT SUM(UnitPrice*OrderQty*(1.00-UnitPriceDiscount)) AS Rev, 
    OrderDate, ProductID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS od
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS o ON od.SalesOrderID=o.SalesOrderID
        AND ProductID BETWEEN 700 and 800
        AND OrderDate >= CONVERT(datetime,'05/01/2002',101)
GROUP BY OrderDate, ProductID
ORDER BY Rev DESC;
GO
--This query can use the above indexed view.
SELECT  OrderDate, SUM(UnitPrice*OrderQty*(1.00-UnitPriceDiscount)) AS Rev
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS od
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS o ON od.SalesOrderID=o.SalesOrderID
        AND DATEPART(mm,OrderDate)= 3
        AND DATEPART(yy,OrderDate) = 2002
GROUP BY OrderDate
ORDER BY OrderDate ASC;
GO
```