# Materialized view in Marketing Performance DB in Azure SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to create a materialized view in a marketing performance database but am getting an error while trying to create .

Using below query to create

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW InvoicesTempM  
WITH (distribution = hash(Invoiceid), FOR_APPEND)  
AS
SELECT Invoiceid, COMPANY from dbo.Invoices
```

Getting error as below:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW'.
> Completion time: 2023-02-09T10:23:12.8418869+05:30

Could anyone help here how can we create materialized view in Azure SQL database, if we cannot please share if there is any alternatives?

Comment: If you read the documentation it appears to me that a materialised view only applies to Azure Synapse. However this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986366/how-to-create-materialized-views-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATERIALIZED VIEW are a concept invented by Oracle. The closest topic in Microsoft SQL Server are INDEXED VIEW, that is :

- a classical view with some limits and the SCHEMABINDING option
- a UNIQUE CLUSTERED index that is created on the view.

In MS SQL Server all Indexed Views are alwyas synchronized with source data (do not need to refresh).

Refer to ["Create indexed views"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16)