# Undo ConfigurationSection changes

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I'm curious if it's possible to undo changes I've made to ConfigurationSection in run-time. I don't want to create lots of variables & set current values, so that when I want to undo them, I can just set them back. I need a simpler way, a method I suppose? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using serialization? You could serialize ConfiguartionSection and then deserialize it to undo. [Here are some tips.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/netfxremoting/thread/1788f50c-5e77-4cb3-8b89-332e6f8382f2)

Comment: can you give some code tutorial? it's just that I've never had an opportunity to work with it... have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you can write it in several approaches. For an instance if you are after to change your application settings at run-time, you can store them in a better place like database in lieu of configuration file and a simple [versioning system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323065/how-to-version-control-a-record-in-a-database) to log a history from user changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). It is ideal for your situation. You can use [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to read and write your backup files.

```
interface ICommandPattern {
    void Execute();
    void Undo();
}

class SaveConfigurationPattern : ICommandPattern {
    string _backupFileName;
    public void Execute()
    {
        // serialize your original and save to the backup file name
        // make changes and save to your config file
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        // copy your backup file over the configuration file
    }
}
```

you can store an array of instances of the `SaveConfigurationPattern` and allow for multi-level undo and redo operations.