# What are the standard/recommended ways to store version-controlled, database data?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, version-control, database

I want to store a blog post in a database. I thought it would be nice to have different versions of that data, much like version controlling does for text files.

So, I imagine it working like a row in a table, that had version control. So, for example, you could retrieve the latest version of that row, or a previous version. You could even branch from that row.

Does anything like this exist?

Possibly useful info:
I am currently using Python, Django & MySQL. I'm experimenting with MongoDB

Edit for clarity/more context:
I'm looking for a solution more tailored towards "version control" of rows than of databases; I'm not so much interested in branching entire databases. For example, I would be able to query the content of blog post at 1/1/2011 and at 1/1/2010 (without switching databases).

Comment: Have you considered using a version control system like git? Would be interesting to see pros and cons of such a solution.

Comment: @milan - since when git versions database **records**?

Comment: The question doesn't say *any* database record, it says blog posts, which are mostly text, so why not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to version control a record in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323065/how-to-version-control-a-record-in-a-database)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I must say this is an interesting question.

In my line of work, I've to save versions of various user inputs. The way I do it, and by all means I don't really know if it's the right way or not, is the following:

I have a `master` table and `revisions` table. I chose these 2 names for the example's sake only.

What master does is stores the following info:

- id (autoincrement)
- version_id (int)

What `revisions` store is the following:

- id
- master_id
- version_id
- rest of the relevant data about entered entity (dates, etc)

What I achieved this way is that I had gotten an ID of, let's say a blog post. If someone edits the post, I'll store that info to `revisions` table. Via triggers I'm incrementing the `version_id` in `revisions` table. After that I update `master` table with the latest `version_id` number. That way I don't have to perform `MAX()` when I want to see what the latest version is.

That way I obtained simple, yet powerful version system of website's content. It's easy to see changes, and it's also extremely fast to obtain data if you abuse some MySQL cool features (in my actual tables, I'm abusing InnoDB's clustered primary key to the max. so the db design is slightly diff. than the one I posted here).

Comment: can you provide information on how master and revision are related?

Comment: Instead of having a "master.version_id" column and needing to update it each time, you can also query join the 2 tables WHERE "revisions.master_id" = "master.id" and use DISTINCT ON "revisions.master_id" and ORDER BY a "revisions.created_at" column which you add to "revisions".

Comment: @KernelJames just because you can use slower approach, it doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 5):

Version control is a complicated topic; doing it right is really challenging which is essentially why even *using* e.g. git can be tough. I wouldn't want to write a full blown version control system.

For simpler requirements, consider this structure, in pseudo-mongodb/JSON:

```
BlogPost {
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "slug" : "how-to-version-my-posts",
    "author" : "cammil",
    "published" : date,
    "lastModified" : date,
    "publicVersion" : 32,
    "draftVersion" : 34,
    "teaserText" : "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
}

BlogPostBody {
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "Version" : 32,
    "Text" : "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
}
```

So the idea here is to store each version separately and a pointer to the current public version and the current version for editors, bloggers, etc.

My answer is a little MongoDB centric (because I built a MongoDB based blog engine for home use), but it should work similarly for any storage system.

Advantages:

- No need to do `MAX` queries of the version number for either public or private posts
- Does not correlate `last edited` to version numbers, which might not be desirable
- Allows versioning even if a certain version is already published
- Can fetch the teaser w/o having to fetch the entire article

Disadvantages:

- Copies the entire text every time. Not a real concern for textual data I guess (try to type 1GB...). Will be a problem for bigger blogging sites, however. Mitigation: Compress text using deflate, delta-compression.
- Needs to update two objects on update