# Can I apply version control system to database data?

Tags: sql, database, git, svn, version-control

We have table `Items`. Someone can add, update or delete rows. Final decision is made by a special person, for example, at the end of the working day. So this person wants to have history of changes and options like `apply changes from John` or `merge John's and Walter's changes and apply` or `rollback to special state of table`.

Is there a way to use VCS over `Items` table rows to have concepts like commits, branches, etc?

P.S. I already read about additional table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/323109/2620352, but it seems too inconvenient and wasteful.

Comment: You will need to build this version control into your system, both in the database and in your application. The closest you would get with a normal version control system would be to export the data into files, and version those, but it would not in any way integrate with your database or your application. In short, no, there is no way to use a normal VCS to do what you want.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, with first line of your comment, I thought version control is possible for DB as well :) ... LOL

Comment: Linked answer you have mentioned; is the only available solution you have on earth at present time unless in future some XYZ company comes with version control for DB.

Comment: What I mean is that there is no existing version control system that works inside a database. They can version your table structure, and such, but if you require the system on a row-for-row basis, integrated into an application, you need to roll your own.

Comment: *“I already read about additional table but it seems too inconvenient and wasteful.”* – Even an existing versioned database system would have to store that information somewhere. Building your own system (into your application, on top of the database) is likely the more flexible and less wasteful solution than having a database in which *everything* was versioned.

Answer (score 3):

You can (and must) version structure's changes.

Depending from used SQL-backend you can have more or less applicable tools, but, from my POV, [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) on top of your usual VCS is easiest and fastest way to start this process: it just add into revision, which contain changes in sources, additional file [changeLog](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html), which have all database-related elementary [changes](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html)

Changelog (in any of possible formats) is text-file, thus - it can be easy diffed|merged

Comment: It is great! But I want to version data changes too.

Comment: Liquibase can version data-changes also - such changeset will contain `Update table` instead of `Alter table` (in MySQL lingo here)