# how use git to manage historical of updates in field text of DB like mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, git, history

I have a mysql db with `Foo` table and `bar` field as text.

I want keep hisorical of each change of the field.

For this moment I have `hirtory` table and I insert in db each version before update `bar` field.

But it's stupid to store all versions when the only change is one letter for exemple.

I want to use git instead of my `hirtory` table, how can I do that?

PS : I'm on app with ruby on rails 4.2

Comment: I'm guessing that you are asking this question as the column stores a large amount of text (possibly for a wiki page, or maybe something different).  I would suggest taking a look at how others have tackled the same (or similar) problems.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/323091/848668) has a couple of links that could be used as a starting point and give you some ideas.

Comment: not realy long text, it's depend... It's articles of rule/law

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Git is for managing source code, not database content. If you need to track changes in your database, using a history table is fine (as you're doing now), but there's also a great gem that takes care of this: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: AFAIK, git doesn't distinguish between plain text and source code.  It's a small nit in regards to your answer, but important to call out.  I suppose the OP could devise a system in which a SQL dump is used (plain text) and then git versions that.  But there's nothing stopping someone from using git to manage history of plain text (non-source code).

Comment: Yes, git manages text files - be it source code, or anything else. But not databases. Yes, you could do an SQL dump and track that in Git, but it's still a bad idea. Matrix can you elaborate more on your use case - why you want to store these versions, and what the domain is, rather than abstracting it as Foo and bar? Then we might be able to help with a better solution.

Comment: It's not a problem if history with git is not in DB... Use case : user can write text of law, and I want show all version of each articles of law and show diff beetween them