# How can I design SQL tables to allow for storage and retrieval of current and historical entity configuration records?

Tags: mysql, sql, storage, record

**TLDR:** How do I structure SQL for saving/retrieval of entity configuration data with ability to know which configuration is current (active) and with ability to keep and retrieve historical configurations that may no longer be active.

**Details**

A sales tool is used to quote products and pair them with a motor.
There are `M` motors (motor frames) and each motor has `P` power configurations.  Each configuration can change over time, so a historical record must be kept of each configuration. I need to know which configuration is active (only one can be active at one time) for a given `(frame, power)` key tuple.  And if it is updated (a new configuration record is created for that key tuple), any of the existing quotes must still be tied to the original no-longer-active `(frame, power)` configuration set.

**Sample Order of Queries**

1. A lookup request for current active configuration for frame.id = 1, power.id = 1.  Version 1 comes back as active
2. I write this configuration into Quote #1 using `(frame, power, version)` n-tuple
3. Company updates frame.id = 1 and power.id = 1 to have a different set of attributes, which becomes version 2 and active.  Old record becomes inactive.
4. I create Quote #2 with this new data.  Quote #1 must retain original configurattion.

How do I best structure/model SQL tables for this to happen?

Here is my preliminary design, where

- frame table represents a motor frame (i.e. 215JM)
- power table represents motor power requirements (380/60)
- configuration is both frame and power as keys, along with a version (1, 2, 3 ..), and whether the configuration is active or not (boolean)
- the payload is the remaining data in `configuration` table, i.e. horsepower (hp), efficiency

[image]

My question is:

- does the configuration table need a unique identifier or is composite key ok?
- does configuration table work as-is for my needs?  i.e. do I need a 4th table specifically for historical records or is what I have now sufficient?

Here is the SQL if required:

```
CREATE TABLE frame (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  size VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE power (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  power VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE configuration (
  frame_id INT NOT NULL,
  power_id INT NOT NULL,
  version INT NOT NULL,
  active TINYINT NOT NULL,
  hp FLOAT NULL,
  efficiency VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (frame_id, version, active, power_id),
  INDEX fk_configuration_power1_idx (power_id ASC),
  INDEX fk_configuration_frame_idx (frame_id ASC),
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: [MariaDB-10.3 - system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/) would be a good way to do this.

Comment: yes if he would be using MariaDB @danblack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for a mysql data versioning system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925435/best-practice-for-a-mysql-data-versioning-system)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the how you intend to use the data. If you intend to use analytical queries (with heavy grouping / filtering by related tables or dimensions) maybe structuring your database like a Kimball-Style Star Schema is the way to go.

This will make your Configurations table a [Slowly Changing Dimension Type-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2_surrogate_key_with_type_3_attribute)

You can intercept the insertion, updates and deletes with triggers to implement the necessary logic to expire old records.

This will also mean that your table will have a new primary key (the Surrogate key) which would uniquely identify the records. Your existing Primary key - the version (frame_id, active, power_id) would become what is known as the business or natural key:

```
CREATE TABLE configuration (
  surrogate_key INT NOT NULL,
  frame_id INT NOT NULL,
  power_id INT NOT NULL,
  active TINYINT NOT NULL,
  hp FLOAT NULL,
  efficiency VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  effective_from DATE NOT NULL,
  effective_to DATE NULL,
  current_flag BOOL,
  PRIMARY KEY (surrogate_key),
  ...;
```

Then you'd join to the other tables using the Surrogate Key (which means that you're joining to specific versions of the natural key).

**PS**: Also is worth considering storing the effective_from and effective_to dates as integers (either EPOX or YYYYMMDD format) for easier filtering and joining.

Hope this helps.