# Where to find user-defined types in table catalogue views

Tags: sql-server, information-schema, catalog, database-metadata

Of sys.objects BL says "Contains a row for each user-defined, schema-scoped object that is created within a database"

The following shows the creation of 2 schema scoped objects, a table and a type, but querying something_here only shows up the table. Why is this, where in the catalogue views do I find this?

```
use master;
go

create database testtttt;
go

use testtttt;
go

select * -- shows nothing of course
from sys.objects 
where name = 'provider';

create table dbo.provider (x int);

select * -- can see new table
from sys.objects 
where name = 'provider';

-- make type, scoped to dbo
create type dbo.provider from int;

select * -- can see table but not new type
from sys.objects 
where name = 'provider';


use master;
go

drop database testtttt;
go
```

(`select @@version` = Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-GDR))

okay, just before posting this StackOverflow suggested this question [Finding SQL Base Type for a User-Defined Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689654/finding-sql-base-type-for-a-user-defined-type) which shows that you can find it by looking in sys.types (tested, it works) except I already looked in the overview of the object catalogue views https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 and `sys.types` did not show up there. What's going on, and are there other kinds of things which behave like this?

Comment: Yes, but type is not an object :D rather, sys.objects contains the actual manifestations of the user defined-types, tables etc. sys.types contains the types from which objects can be potentially created or data types like INTs and their aliases.

Comment: FWIW I raised an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/8998) about the inaccuracy of the documentation on this subject.

Comment: @siggemannen This is further confused by the fact there are Table Types, which are also schema-scoped but show up in `sys.objects` under a different name.

Comment: @ThomA: thanks for raising this. Is it me or is BOL not nearly as good as it used to be?

Comment: @siggemannen: seems I don't know what a database object is. I assumed it was anything that could stand alone, like a table, but not like a trigger (because triggers need tables). Other than objects and types, are you aware of any other variety of 'thing'?

Comment: @Charlieface: now you mention it, I remember seeing that too :(

Comment: A trigger is an object, as is a constraint. Both have schema-scoped names, not object-scoped. They are both present in `sys.objects`. But eg indexes are not schema-scoped and do not appear there.

Comment: *"Is it me or is BOL not nearly as good as it used to be?"* No, I think the documentation (it's not really referred to as "BOL" any more) is better now-a-days, especially because it's open source and therefore the community can also contribute.