# Sql Server variable loose it's value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL server 2008, I have a table which stored the created Job_id for each job and then for deleting the job I use a stored procedure (below) which gets the ID and tries to delete the job but although I'm sure that the job exists with @ScheduleReportID but the following select always returns null ! 
Job_id is of type UniqueIdentifier in tbRptSchedule

```
    declare @job_name nvarchar(max)
        SELECT @job_name = name 
        from msdb.dbo.sysjobs with(nolock) 
        where job_id = (select job_id from dbo.tbRptSchedule with(nolock) where ScheduledReportID = @ScheduledReportID)

        IF @job_name IS NULL
        BEGIN
         RAISERROR ('Cannot find Job identifier',16,1)
        END
```

Comment: Maybe you should use the sp_delete_job http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187850.aspx

Comment: I'm using it but first I need to find the job name or job id

Comment: Didn't you say you stored the job id?

Comment: Silly question but do you have the relevant permissions to query sysjobs

Comment: Query seems to be okay... Please confirm about the Database name "msdb" from where the job name is selected.

Comment: @nunespascal yes I store the JobID and here I want to retrieve it and the problem is that I cannot !

Comment: @Kamal yes I have permission to sysjobs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `declare @jobname nvarchar(max)` has something to do with the error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) sysname is equivalent to a NOT NULL varchar(128).