# Where can I find out the specifics/differences between various SQL DB data types?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I found a list of the datatypes for SQL DB (formerly Azure DB) here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336233.aspx

...but nothing on what exactly each data type is. For example, I need to know:

```
Since there is no Boolean type, what should I use in lieu of bool in SQL DB?

What is the difference between *datetime* and *datetime2* in SQL DB?

What is the difference between *datetime* (and *datetime2*) and *timestamp* in SQL DB?

What is the *sysname* datatype in SQL DB?
```

Comment: All these questions can be answered by a simple Google query. Keep in mind that SQL Azure is just SQL Server, so search for SQL Server data types.

Comment: I tried that, actually a Bing query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your questions are SQL Server questions, which answers have no difference between Azure and non-Azure.

There is no BOOLEAN type in any version of SQL Server. There is ["BIT" data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx), which maps to a .NET BOOL data type.

[DateTime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) is more precise (up to 1/100000 of a second) then [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) (1/100 of a second) data type in SQL Server (respectively Windows Azure SQL Database).

DateTime/DateTime2 are SQL Server data types that map to a DateTime .NET type, whilst [timestamp is an automatically generated sequence of numbers which is auto incremented on every row update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and is used for row versioning and concurrency management in SQL Server / Data aware applications

What is sysname - [What is SYSNAME data type in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server)

Please try harder the internet search engines, before asking questions here. And please ask concrete questions!

As already marked by other users - there is nothing AZURE in your questions.

Comment: Based on this info, I tried to update a table in my Azure SQL DB portal, changing a column from char[1] with a default value of 'F' to a bit column. 

But it wouldn't allow me to do it, saying, "An error was encountered while applying the changes.
An exception occurred while executing the Transact-SQL statement: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DUCKBILLEDPLATYPUS_PERMISSIONS] DROP COLUMN [AllowAccess].
The object 'ColumnDefault_21d83918-0ce9-4c2d-bb8d-957107c80c63' is dependent on column 'AllowAccess'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN AllowAccess failed because one or more objects access this column."

Comment: So based on your comments, any timestamp column I add will be automatically populated? I don't have to specify it as such, the data type itself makes it do that inherently and unerrantly?

Comment: second comment - YES. First comment - I would be surprised if you could change a CHAR(1) column to A BIT column. BIT column represents a BIT (i.e. 0 or 1). There is no mechanism in SQL Server to map 'F' to 1, or char to number. You could possibly successfully alter an INT column to a BIGINT or FLOAT. But a CHAR to BIT - this won't happen.

Comment: Yes, I know that an 'F' wouldn't be valid for a Bit. I guess I wasn't clear; I was trying to change the Char[1] column with a default value of 'F' to a Bit column with a default value of 0. Since there is no data in the table yet, I don't see why I can't change its data type. It wouldn't even allow me to delete the first column and then add it back (so to speak) as a different data type.