# multiline can stored text just 128 Character

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I got stuck on need to store a data from multiline textbox to sql server database and write a code like this

ASP.NET

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductFeatures" runat="server" CssClass="full-width-input" TextMode="multiline"  Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductFeatures", txtProductFeatures.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />"))
```

i tried to store lorem

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ultrices luctus semper. Mauris facilisis ac mauris id commodo. Cras non efficitur magna, non sollicitudin erat. Maecenas blandit nisl a est mollis, eu luctus mi euismod. Mauris aliquam lorem nec risus vehicula, vel faucibus ante tincidunt. Sed erat odio, fermentum at nulla ut, fringilla gravida orci. Quisque interdum, massa sed laoreet auctor, ipsum nisi ornare libero, a dignissim risus nunc ac magna. Suspendisse tortor mi, blandit id ipsum ac, mattis finibus metus. Morbi euismod eleifend odio et dictum. In semper sit amet mauris et gravida. Suspendisse vitae pharetra mi, ac posuere tortor. Proin enim nisl, pretium ac ipsum sed, vulputate viverra purus. Aliquam nec est et ante rutrum sollicitudin. Etiam tempor velit erat, non ultricies eros varius vitae. Proin consequat tempor diam, sed imperdiet metus ullamcorper nec. Morbi ut molestie lectus.
>   In tincidunt egestas odio a luctus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin aliquam quam feugiat aliquam dictum. Proin massa eros, accumsan vel faucibus eget, commodo quis tortor. Vivamus quam odio, porttitor eu massa eget, tincidunt lobortis libero. Fusce congue ultricies tellus pulvinar sagittis. Aenean quis lectus eu nulla porta iaculis eget et nisi.
>   Aenean congue diam neque, tempus tincidunt urna consequat ut. Aenean maximus lectus eu tellus molestie, nec auctor est dapibus. Nullam bibendum sed est sed euismod. Nunc consectetur, orci a aliquam condimentum, lectus neque vehicula sem, nec aliquam enim neque sit amet leo. Morbi nulla augue, mollis eget nunc eget, commodo fringilla est. Quisque pretium vehicula tincidunt. Praesent malesuada massa vel erat faucibus, vel tempor sapien fringilla. Aliquam lacinia, sapien ut dictum laoreet, tellus sem sollicitudin justo, volutpat tristique libero risus nec purus. Morbi ornare erat a justo gravida malesuada. Nullam placerat erat nunc, vel aliquet neque massa nunc.

And they're show just

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi faucibus ultricies aliquet. Suspendisse nunc tellus, finibus et l

i tried a few trick and code on stack but it doesn't matter

datatype in Database is = `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: Have you specified datatype as NVARCHAR(MAX) for the parameter @ProductFeatures in stored procedure.

Comment: i use datatype sysname

Comment: sysname is a built in datatype limited to 128 Unicode characters. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server.

Comment: OH MY GOD !!!!!!, It's perfectly work thank youuuuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

When DataType is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` You Need to Use `-1` as `Max Size`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductFeatures", SqlDbType.NVarChar,
-1).Value=txtProductFeatures.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
```

**Read This:**
[can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: it's show Internal Server Error and i cut the semicolon off because character is not valid

Comment: @touchchaieuapermchokchai can you tell me what is exact error/Exception

Comment: i solved a Internal server error, and i tried to put a lorem again and it's store the same as i did it's just 128 character