# Transact SQL Server Error 105

Tags: sql-server, transactions, distributed-transactions

Hey guys  I am creating a store procedure but I am getting this error: 
`105 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Guadalajara,Jal'.`, and i have looked through several websites, sadly I haven found an answer.
Here is my code:

```
    Alter Procedure Insertar
(
    @Vuelos nvarchar(6),
    @Aero nvarchar(20),
    @Sal nvarchar(40),
    @Ori varchar(50),
    @Des varchar(50),
    @Lle nvarchar(40),
    @Per nvarchar(1),
    @Nom nvarchar(25),
    @Nodo nvarchar(13)
)
AS
    BEGIN
        Set XACT_ABORT ON
        Begin DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
            BEGIN TRY
                Insert into Reservaciones values
                (
                  @Vuelos,@Aero,@Sal,@Ori,@Des,@Lle,@Per,@Nom,GETDATE()
                )

                DECLARE @cmd as sysname;
                SET @cmd ='Insert into ['+@Nodo+'].'+'['+@Aero+'].[dbo].[Reservaciones] values'+
                '('''+@Vuelos+''','''+@Aero+''','''+@Sal+''','''+@Ori+''','''+@Des+''','''+@Lle+''','+@Per+','''+@Nom+''',GETDATE())'
                EXEC(@cmd)

                SET @cmd='Update ['+@Nodo+'].['+@Aero+'].[dbo].[Vuelos] Set Dis-='+@Per+' where Vuelo='+@Vuelos;
                EXEC(@cmd)
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                PRINT ERROR_NUMBER()
                PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
                ROLLBACK
            END CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                commit
    END
```

and this is what I input into the stored procedure

```
EXEC Insertar 'AM 500','Mexicana','2015-05-13 19:00:00.0','Guadalajara,Jalisco,Mexico','San Diego,California,Estados Unidos','2015-05-13 21:21:00.0',3,'gus','Gustavo\Nodo1';
```

To be more specific the issue is that sql is cutting half of whats in variable `@Ori` however I have debug and in that variable and it is complete, I have checked and yes that variable does have enough space for the text.

I appreciate any kind of help you guys can provide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using the wrong datatype for @cmd.
[sysname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server) datatype has a limited length of 128 Unicode characters.

I would also advise you to try to avoid dynamic sql since it's usually very vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) attacks.

Comment: Thank you it worked by changing to a different datatype. Ok so what would be your recommendation instead of using dynamic sql?. I decided to use then since I was using linked servers.

Comment: At this moment I have 4 but it is planned to add 5 more in a near future.

Comment: and on each of them you have several databases that contains Reservaciones and Vuelos tables, or just one?

Comment: + [Read this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/)

Comment: Thanks for the article I'll take a look in to it. Yeah most of the databases will both tables. Which will be the only ones that communicate with each other, tha database do have other tables but there is no need to access them from another place.

Comment: Actualy, I wanted to know if you make a table with the linked server name in one column and the database name on another column will you have the server names unique on that table. If so, you can do that and don't need to send the database name to the stored procedure