# What SqlDbType should be used when creating a table?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I don't know if this is really needed... but I *would* like write as robust code as possible, so:

What `SqlDbType` should be used when creating a table? `SqlDbType.NChar`? Or would there be a problem with a Unicode table name? Or perhaps one of the `Var` types because the length is unknown? I'm used to thinking about these types in the context of a database row, not table, so I'm not sure what should be used here.

**EDIT**

For example, a line like:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameterName,SqlDbType.NChar){ Value = value });
```

for a `CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: Which value that you try to parameterize exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül The value is a simple string, e.g. `table1`. I'm just asking for the correct **SqlDbType**.

Comment: The documentation on SqlDbType says it applies to fields, not tables.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm not sure [they meant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to exclude tables. It's simply unusual to be used in that way. But if so - Then how _do_ I parametrize a table name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can't* parameterize your table name or column names or any other database objects. You can *only* parameterize your values.

You can *still* using string concatenation it **but** getting your table name as an input is too risky in my opinion. You should either perform very stringent validation on the table name before putting it into the SQL, or have a white-listed set of valid table names, in order to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Other than that, [parameterized statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) is only for [DML Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848766.aspx) not [DDL statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx).

Comment: Thank. But I've updated the question. For example for creating a table.

Comment: @ispiro Even if you find a _correct_ type for your column name (which looks like `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL` based on your comment) you should not do that in my opinion. This is **not** what parameterized queries are for.

Comment: I completely agree about not letting a user choose a table name. However, I would like to use this for avoiding **un**intentional mistakes when creating a table name. But as I said - I agree with you.

Comment: My code fails with `Incorrect syntax near '@abc'.` So it seems you're right.

Answer (score 2):

All object names in SQL Server are of `sysname` datatype. Don't know if the SqlDbType contains sysname, but it is functionally identical to `nvarchar(128)`, so you can use this.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably it. (And I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5720277/939213) talking about it).

Comment: My code fails with `Incorrect syntax near '@abc'.` So it seems it can't be done. But your answer is helpful. Thanks.