# Maximum field name(column) length in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, field-names

Hi everyone i'm trying to create a table with columns that is more than 128 of text.

is it possible to increase the field name(column) length in SQL Server

Comment: Maximum length of the `SYSNAME` data type is 128 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server

Comment: 128 is already a lot. May I ask why do you need something longer?

Comment: we will use the questions in surveys as the column name, so if we have 10 questions, 2 of it is for narrative(this is the problem i need to solve, the questions for narrative are sometimes very long and we can't create a solution that is hard coded)

Comment: Don't embed *data* in column names.

Comment: We will use the field names(Column) as a value,legend in PowerBI. do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn nvarchar(256) NULL
```

You could put in it any number below 4000 otherwise go for nvarchar(max)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms190273%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use the PIVOT function in SQL Server, and keep the questions numbered 1,2,3 etc. Great example of this is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)