# SQL error table name using [,] and '

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have some problems/questions with the usage of `[`,`]` and  `'` in table names.
For example why this working

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [O'test]
      ,[NumeNOU]
  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[O'conor]
```

and this not

```
use dbname
GO
DECLARE @COUNT int
SELECT @COUNT = Count(*) FROM  dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where TABLE_NAME = [dbname].[dbo].[O'conor]
PRINT @COUNT
```

with the error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The multi-part identifier
>   "dbname.dbo.O'conor" could not be bound.

or this

```
use dbname
    GO
    DECLARE @COUNT int
    SELECT @COUNT = Count(*) FROM  dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where TABLE_NAME = [O'conor]
    PRINT @COUNT
```

with the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'O''conor'.

but is working like this

```
use dbname
        GO
        DECLARE @COUNT int
        SELECT @COUNT = Count(*) FROM  dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where TABLE_NAME = 'O''conor'
        PRINT @COUNT
```

Comment: TABLE_NAME = [dbname].[dbo].[O'conor]

This one needs to surrounded by quotes e.g. '[dbname].[dbo].[O'conor]'

Comment: The one with `WHERE TABLE_NAME = [O'conor]` is definitely incorrect because you're trying to use it as a column name, you would instead do `WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'O''conor'`

Comment: The error messages are entirely correct, those tables does not have a column with that name. You might want to look for a row where the table name is that but then you need to use a string literal, and not reference a column that does not exist. So what is the question? You say "this does not work, but this does". Is the question "why?" ?

Comment: The question was why in the first case it worked and in those 2 it didn't. I am not specifying anywhere the column name . Somebody posted a good answer but deleted it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 + 2

```
use dbname
GO
DECLARE @COUNT int
SELECT @COUNT = Count(*) FROM  dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where TABLE_NAME = [dbname].[dbo].[O'conor]
PRINT @COUNT

use dbname
GO
DECLARE @COUNT int
SELECT @COUNT = Count(*) FROM  dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where TABLE_NAME = [O'conor]
PRINT @COUNT
```

Thess queries will not work since TABLE_NAME expects a [`sysname`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server) value but you supply an identifier.

3

```
use dbname
GO
DECLARE @COUNT int
SELECT @COUNT = Count(*) FROM  dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where TABLE_NAME = 'O''conor'
PRINT @COUNT
```

This query works since you are supplying a `sysname` value.

Side note: It's better to use object names that contains only letters, numbers and underscores, that way you don't need to use the square brackets around them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)