# How can sysname = null in this SQL Server system stored procedure if sysname cannot be null?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I read that [sysname cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server), yet in the definition of the system procedure `sp_grantdbaccess`, I see the assignment of null to one of the procedure's arguments (if I read this right). How can this be?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sys].[sp_grantdbaccess]
    @loginame   sysname,
    @name_in_db sysname = NULL OUT
```

Comment: If you read the complete answer at the link you provided you will see that for `SYSNAME` `NOT NULL` is the default, but it can also be overridden, which is effectively what is happening here.

Comment: The default nullability of a type is ignored in some circumstances, and stored procedure parameters are one of those. Variables are another: `DECLARE @n SYSNAME` will work just fine, and it always produces a variable with an initial value of `NULL`. For stored procedure parameters, what matters is whether or not the parameter was supplied, not its value -- `NULL` is always permitted. `sp_grantdbaccess @loginame=NULL` produces an error only because `sp_grantdbaccess` explicitly checks (by way of `sp_validname`) -- the engine does not prevent the `NULL` from being assigned.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - the accepted answer quotes the official docs as saying "sysname is a system-supplied user-defined data type that is functionally equivalent to nvarchar(128), except that it is not nullable" which conflicts with the later comment that null is simply the default value, which is why I asked the question - I'd have thought the official docs take precedence over the answer comment.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - From your explanation I deduce the quoted documentation probably means that a column of data type sysname may not be persisted with a null value - as opposed to meaning that a variable of that type may not be null within the scope of a procedure, etc.

Comment: That's also not true. I'd better write up an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"`SYSNAME` cannot be `NULL`" is just not true. The linked question's answer is correct when it says that it's equivalent to `NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL` as a *default* -- and then effectively *only* in column definitions. Compare:

```
-- When not specified, columns are NULL
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON  

-- Works
CREATE TABLE T(N NVARCHAR(128)); INSERT T DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT * FROM T
GO
DROP TABLE T
GO

-- When not specified, columns are NOT NULL
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON OFF

-- Error: can't insert NULL
CREATE TABLE T(N NVARCHAR(128)); INSERT T DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT * FROM T
GO
DROP TABLE T
GO
```

And now try the same with `SYSNAME`:

```
-- When not specified, columns are NULL
SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON  

-- Error: SYSNAME is NOT NULL, regardless of defaults
CREATE TABLE T(N SYSNAME); INSERT T DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT * FROM T
GO
DROP TABLE T
GO
```

But this does not mean `SYSNAME` cannot be `NULL`, all we have to do is say it may be:

```
-- Works
CREATE TABLE T(N SYSNAME NULL); INSERT T DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT * FROM T
GO
DROP TABLE T
GO
```

In almost all other contexts where a type is used (variables, stored procedure parameters), we cannot specify `NULL` or `NOT NULL` and `NULL` values are always allowed, so this `NOT NULL` metadata is very rarely relevant. It's no accident that the above code is using regular tables: if you try the same thing with a table variable, you'll find that `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` is ignored and `NULL` is always the default for columns, if not specified, so the only relevant cases are:

```
-- Can't insert NULL
DECLARE @T TABLE (N SYSNAME); INSERT @T DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT * FROM T@
GO

-- OK
DECLARE @T TABLE (N SYSNAME NULL); INSERT @T DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT * FROM @T
GO
```

Comment: Thank you - the answers have taught me to think about the different contexts of column definitions vs variables, and that the MS remark is not strictly true that reads "sysname is a system-supplied user-defined data type that is functionally equivalent to nvarchar(128), except that it is not nullable"; it should probably have "by default" appended.