# Table name placeholder - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to do something like this? People is the name of the table.

```
declare @placeholder varchar(20) = 'People'
select * from @placeholder
```

Or something like this where the table name is People_Backup.

```
declare @placeholder varchar(20) = '_Backup'
select * from People@placeholder
```

And is there a way to add in dynamic sql the value of a variable? 
something like this:

```
declare @placeholder nvarchar(20) = 'people'
declare @name nvarchar(30) = 'antony'

declare @query nvarchar(1000) = 'select * from ' + @placeholder + ' where 
first_name=' + @name 
exec sp_executesql @query
```

I mean: without do this

```
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@name varchar(30)', @name
```

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: use dynamic sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean: without do this `exec sp_executesql @query, N'@name varchar(30)', @name`

Yes, you can do that as

```
--Use MAX instead of 1000
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @placeholder + ' WHERE first_name = '''+@name +'''';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 6):

Not without dynamic SQL.
Parameters in SQL are placeholders for *data*, and can't be used as placeholders for anything else (which includes *commands* such as `select`, `update` etc' and *identifiers* such as database name, schema name, table name, column name etc').

The only way to parameterize table names is to use dynamic SQL - meaning you must build a string containing the SQL you want to execute, and then execute it.
Beware - dynamic SQL might be an open door for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks - so you must do it wisely - here are some ground rules:

- **Always** white-list your identifiers (using system tables or views such as `sys.Tables` or `Information_schema.Columns`)
- **Always** use [`sysname`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720212/what-is-sysname-data-type-in-sql-server) as the datatype for identifiers.

  > The `sysname` data type is used for table columns, variables, and stored procedure parameters that store object names. The exact definition of sysname is related to the rules for identifiers. Therefore, it can vary between instances of SQL Server.
- **Never** pass SQL commands or clauses in parameters - `set @placeholder = 'select a, b, c'` or `set @placeholder = 'where x = y'` **is a security hazard!**
- **Always** use parameters for data. Never concatenate parameters into your sql string: `set @sql = 'select * from table where x = '+ @x` is a security hazard. Always create your dynamic SQL to use parameters as parameters: `set @sql = 'select * from table where x = @x'`
- **Always** use `sp_executeSql` to execute your dynamic SQL statement, not `EXEC(@SQL)`.
  For more information, read Kimberly Tripp's [EXEC and sp_executesql – how are they different?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/)
- **Always** wrap identifiers with [`QUOTENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to ensure correct query even when identifiers include chars like white-spaces

To recap - a safe version of what you are asking for (with an additional dynamic where clause to illustrate the other points) is something like this:

```
@DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'People',
         @ColumnName sysname = 'FirstName'
         @Search varchar(10) = 'Zohar';

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Information_Schema.Columns
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000) = 
    'SELECT * FROM +' QUOTENAME(@TableName) +' WHERE '+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) +' LIKE ''%''+ @Search +''%'';'

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Search varchar(10)', @Search

END
-- you might want to raise an error if not
```

To answer your question after edited directly:

> I mean: without do this exec sp_executesql @query, N'@name varchar(30)', @name

Yes, you can do it without using `sp_executeSql`, **but it's dangerous** - it will enable an attacker to use something like `'';DROP TABLE People;--` as the value of `@name`, so that when you execute the sql, your `People` table will be dropped.

To do that, you will need to wrap the `@name` with `'` -

```
declare @placeholder nvarchar(20) = 'people'
declare @name nvarchar(30) = 'antony'

declare @query nvarchar(1000) = 'select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@placeholder) + ' where 
first_name=''' + @name +''''
exec(@query)
```

Comment: And one more: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @HABO Correct! I don't know why I didn't write it in the first place. Adding to the list

Comment: A while ago I've written a post based on this answer in What the # do I know? called [The do’s and don’ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server-%ef%bb%bf/). It contains a bit more information.