# SQL 2008 returning a change in an ID field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, triggers, case-when

Im not even sure how to write this out. Would I put the logic in a case when?

```
select personnum, orgid, eventdate
from dbo.totals
where eventdate = '10-08-2013'
```

There can be multiple orgids applied to a personnum throughout a day. When there is a change in orgid, I want to return that change.

Comment: Please see my auditing table with triggers response.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890868/how-to-store-historical-records-in-a-history-table-in-sql-server/19144370#19144370  This solution will keep track of an audit trail in xml data format.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the schema of the table and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a `trigger` to write to a separate table which contains details of the changes.

You would create an `update trigger` on the table in question, and use the values in `inserted` and/or `deleted` to detail the changes.

Comment: I do not want to update the field though. I simply want to extract the data when a user changes his orgid column. I feel like I don't need to create a table for this. I just want to display what changed.