# Triggers-Implementation Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am making 2 tables for implementing triggers –

```
create table emp(id int primary key identity(1,1),
name char(40),
salary varchar(50),
gender char(40),
departmentid int);

insert into emp(name,salary,gender,departmentid) values ('jimmi',4800,'Male',4);

create table emp_audit
(
id int primary key identity(1,1),
audit varchar(60)
);
alter trigger trigger_em_update on emp for update 
as begin
Declare @Id int
Declare @oldname char(40),@newname char(40)
Declare @oldsal int,@newsal int
Declare @oldgen char(40),@newgen char(40)
Declare @olddeptid int,@newdeptid int

Declare @auditstring nvarchar(max)


--select * from deleted;

select  * into #temptable from inserted;

while(Exists(select id from #temptable)) --boolean condition if there are rows are not
Begin
    set @auditstring =''

    --if there are many rows we still select the first one

    select Top 1 @Id =id,@newname=name,@newgen=gender,@newsal=salary,@newdeptid=departmentid
    from #temptable;

    select Top 1 @Id =id,@oldname=name,@oldgen=gender,@oldsal=salary,@olddeptid=departmentid
    from deleted where @Id=id;

    set @auditstring=' Employee with id= '+CAST(@Id as varchar(20))+ ' changed '
    if(@oldname<>@newname)
        set @auditstring=@auditstring + 'name from '+ @oldname +' to' +@newname

    if(@oldsal<>@newsal)
        set @auditstring=@auditstring + ' salary from '+ @oldsal +' to  ' +@newsal

    if(@oldgen<>@newgen)
    set @auditstring=@auditstring + '   gender from ' + @oldgen + ' to  ' + @newgen

--  if(@olddeptid<>@newdeptid)
    --set @auditstring=@auditstring + ' departmentid from ' + cast(@olddeptid as nvarchar(5))+' to  ' 

insert into emp_audit values(@auditstring)

delete from #temptable where id=@Id

end
end
when i use update query
update emp set name='vishi',gender='male',salary='4000',departmentid=3 where id=3;
```

It gives an error

> "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' Employee with id= 3 changed name from james                                    tovishi                                    salary from ' to data type int.
>   "
>   i don't know how to solve this..can you solve this..

Comment: Do any of the columns being logged allow NULLs?

Comment: In `emp` you declare `salary varchar(50)`, but in the trigger `Declare @oldsal int,@newsal int`. You ought to decide on a single datatype. Adding quotes around values makes interpreting the audit easier, e.g. `from 'Foo ' to 'Foo'`. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890868/how-to-store-historical-records-in-a-history-table-in-sql-server/11891352#11891352): "Logging triggers should always be set to fire last. Otherwise, a subsequent trigger may rollback the original transaction, but the log table will have already been updated. This is a confusing state of affairs."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line:

```
if(@oldsal<>@newsal)
    set @auditstring=@auditstring + ' salary from '+ @oldsal +' to  ' +@newsal
```

Should be:

```
if(@oldsal<>@newsal)
    set @auditstring=@auditstring+ ' salary from '+CAST(@oldsal AS NVARCHAR(100)) 
       +' to  ' +CAST(@newsal AS NVARCHAR(100))
```

A couple of thoughts:

1. It is a good practice to end each statement with semicolon
2. `@oldsal<>@newsal` won't detect changing from `NULL` to value or value to `NULL`
3. Row-by-row processing is not best practice from performance perspective(especially inside trigger's body)
4. `set @auditstring=@auditstring +....` could be replaced with `set @auditstring += ...`
5. If any value that you are using to concatenate auditstring is `NULL` variable will be set to `NULL`.
6. I do not recommend to store name/variable as `CHAR(size)`, it is better to use `VARCHAR(size)`
7. Tracking what has changed as single string will require parsing in the future(unless you only want to display it).

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for giving me some tips regarding this.Once i do update in my trigger if problem occurs i will ask again.

Comment: All good thoughts. This can be done with a set-based operation by joining the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables on `Id`, using `CASE` expressions to detect changed values, and using `FOR XML` to build the audit string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of the columns used with `+` is a number, probably salary.  But your trigger is way too complicated.

SQL is a set-based language.  So use the sets when you can:

```
alter trigger trigger_em_update on emp for update 
as
begin
    insert into emp_audit (auditstring) -- guessing the name
        select ('Employee with id k= ' + CAST(@Id as varchar(20))+ ' changed ' +
                (case when @oldname <> @newname
                      then 'name from '+ @oldname +' to ' + @newname + ' '
                      else ''
                 end) +
                (case when @oldsal <> @oldsal
                      then 'salary from '+ convert(varchar(255), @oldsal) +' to ' + concvert(varchar(255), @newsal) + ' '
                      else ''
                 end) +
                (case when @oldgen <> @newgen
                      then 'gender from '+ convert(varchar(255), @oldgen) +' to ' + concvert(varchar(255), @newgen) + ' '
                      else ''
                 end) +
                (case when @olddeptid <> @newdeptid
                      then 'departmentid from '+ convert(varchar(255), @olddeptid) +' to ' + concvert(varchar(255), @newdeptid) + ' '
                      else ''
                 end)
                ) as auditstring
        from inserted i join
             deleted d
             on i.id = d.id;
end;
```