# How to convert all table data to nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a trigger to log data whenever any CRUD operation with my tables happen. 
For example:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Data_Created]
ON [Project_MyTable1]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO [Project_Logs] (Operation, LogData)
        SELECT 'INSERT', ID
        FROM INSERTED
```

It works just fine, but there is plenty of columns in my table which I'd like to see in my log data column. I'm struggling to find any way to extract all row data and convert it to `nvarchar` or `xml` (? maybe) except by concatenation.

Already tried a lot of things like:

```
Convert(nvarchar, (Select * FROM INSERTED))
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If you want to keep a history use a history table (either within your production table, or as a separate entity), or temporal table. Don't pivot all your data from a single insert into a "logging" table. You'll find it unmanagable.

Comment: You should also see the 'Change Data Capture' (CDC) feature of the SQL server for the Audit log.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If the data is not `NVARCHAR` why do you want to store it in that format? You don't want your actual data to be different in any way of your logged data. In addition, you double your logged data size.

Comment: Found answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890868/how-to-store-historical-records-in-a-history-table-in-sql-server). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

based on [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> -- CONVERT Syntax:   CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )